# How to get facebook group data

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I would like to retrieve the entire posts of a Facebook group.
The group is open with no restrictions and i am not admin in that group.
Is there an easy way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Group ID, just take a look at the docs for example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed

`/group-id/feed` is what you need.

Comment: It says 'GET /v2.5/{group-id}/feed HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com' How do i make http/php code from it. I just dont get it

Comment: your question is way too broad for a more detailed answer, please edit your question and include the code you have tried so far and a detailed description of where you got stuck. there is code for the php sdk in the docs, and it should be easy to turn those HTTP requests into some code with PHP cURL if you don´t want to use the php sdk.

Comment: Thx, passed that issue. Now the curl gets hebrew site but prints gibrish \u200eDors \u05e0\u05d3\u05dc\u05df\u20 instead of real hebrew chars. What can i do within curl code?

Comment: try utf8. that´s all i can say, dealing with language issues is a completely different problem.

Comment: I just found that the problem of gibrish content only occurs on Facebook Hebrew groups while other Hebrew sites work fine. Any idea how to overcome it?

Comment: without your exact code and detailed information, it´s nearly impossible to help. you should create a separate thread for it though. and again: be a LOT more detailed, include what you have tried so far and all the relevant code.